# ReportViewer Control vs Report Manager's ReportViewer

Tags: .net, reporting-services

Whenever i am loading a report in reportviewer control of aspx page, the parameters i passed to report are not visible in address bar. However, accessing report server with Url access show parameters in address bar (which i don't want to do). Here is an example of later scenario.

http://example.net/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Reports/DemoReport&rs%3ACommand=Render&rs%3AFormat=HTML4.0&rc%3AParameters=False&**Parameter1=ABC&Parameter2=12**

Is there any way to hide these parameters form URL. I have tried to access report server using POST method but when report manager handle the request, parameters appear in URL. Any suggestions?